# Test Driven Development in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, tdd

I've recently been working on some bigger projects in Flash and would really like to be able to use Test Driven Development but haven't found a great way to do so. I'd imagine its a bit harder to do in flash as most of its projects require heavy user interactivity (drag and drop with mouse, keyboard input to move etc...).

Does anybody know how I could effectively use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conrad Winchester had a talk on TDD with [FlexUnit and Hudson at the London Flash Platform User Group](http://www.lfpug.com/flexunit-4-and-hudson/). Slides and Video avaialble.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

For a couple of the Flash projects I've been working on, we use [ASUnit](http://asunit.org/) to test components in isolation, and [Selenium-Flex](http://code.google.com/p/sfapi/) to handle functional testing.

There are undoubtedly alternatives, but this seems to work for us.